# jquery deleting a table row help

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some code like this to delete a row then display a dialog.

the first time i click delete id removes the row straight away.
but on any subsequent rows i try to delete i sometimes need multiple clicks before it removes the row.

sometimes the dialog shows and the row is still there!

what is the matter?

EDIT - The db gets updated correctly but the row still remains. its quite erratic sometimes it removes sometimes i have to click twice.

```
$(".delete-item").click(function () {
            var itemId = $(this).attr("id").split('-')[1];
            var iType = $(this).attr("id").split('-')[0];

            $.post('/User/Delete/', { id: itemId, itemType: iType },function (json) {
                if (json.success) {

                    console.log("#row-"+itemId);
                    $("#row-"+itemId).hide('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });

                    //$("#dialog-success-delete").dialog("open");


                } else {
                    if(json.error=="unknown"){
                        $("#dialog-unknown-error").dialog("open");
                    }
                    if(json.error=="unauthenticated"){
                        $("#dialog-unauthenticated").dialog("open");
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: You should show the rest of your code; we can't see the click handler for your delete button, which is likely where the problem lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem was I had multiple rows with the same id on the page!
I was using tabs and the tables were in separate tabs!.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a timing issue - if the callback for the animation has not happened before another row is clicked, itemId would reference the wrong item.

Change to:

```
$("#row-"+itemId).hide('slow', function(){ $(this).remove(); });
```

Since the modal is only sometimes showing, i'm sure there is another problem as well.

There is a note on the [post api](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) about silently failing

> a request with jQuery.post() returns
>   an error code, it will fail silently
>   unless the script has also called the
>   [global .ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/)

This would be my best guess, the success callback is never happening because of a server error.

Comment: the modal always shows even if the row is still there...btw added more info above

Answer (score 0):

Verify your selector is correct.  Use Chrome, or Firefox + Firebug + Firequery, and `console.log($"#row-"+itemId)` where you have the `.remove()`.  The most likely cause is that itemId does not line up with row ID's like you expect them to.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you should include the dialog in the function after the hide takes place so it only pops up when the row has been hidden. Second, use the `this` selector after you get in. This verifies you're always working on the same row that was initially clicked. Lastly, I don't see a `click` method in your code so be sure you're doing it correctly as well.

This code works for me in a quick test:

```
$("#row-"+itemId).click(function() {
  $(this).hide('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $("#dialog-success-delete").dialog("open");
  });
});
```